# Find rows in the list of objects

Tags: python-2.7

Need your help. There is a list (array) that consists of class objects, how to find the item (rows) in this list, for example: a mobile phone or a name? I have a function `findByName` and `findByPhone` by they don't work!

```
class Database:
    name = 'n/a'
    phone = 'n/a'
    list = []
    copy_list = []

    class Rec:
        def __init__(self, nam, phon):
            self.name = nam
            self.phone = phon
        def __str__(self):
            return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.phone)
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        pass
    def addRecord(self, name, phone):
        self.list.append(Database.Rec(name,phone))
    def findByName(self, name):
        res = self.findSubStr(name)
        if len(res) == 0:
            print ("Sorry, nothing match in names for " + name)
        return res
    def findByPhone(self, phone):
        res = self.findSubStr(phone)
        if len(res) == 0:
            print ("Sorry, nothing match in phones for " + phone)
        return res
    def findSubStr(self, substr):
        res = []
        for el in self.list:
            if substr in self.list:
                res.append(el)
        return res
def fun_input():
    print ("Please enter the name")
    name = raw_input()
    print ("Please enter phone number")
    phone = raw_input()
    db.addRecord(name, phone)
def fun_output():
    db.out()
def fun_find():
    print ("Please choose an option for which you want to search:")
    print ("1 - Find for name")
    print ("2 - Find for phone number")
            ph = int(raw_input())
            if ph == 1:
            print ("Please enter the name for find:")
            phName = raw_input()
            db.findByName(phName)
        if ph == 2:
            print ("Please enter the phone number for find:")
            phPhone = raw_input()
            db.findByPhone(phPhone)
```

Comment: The indentation needs fixing, but that doesn't relate to the problem you stated. After fixing indentation, you code is two classes, but how do you use your functions? I get no prompt for input and no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of Rec's, which has two fields, name and phone.  But you are searching as if the list is a list of items which might be phone numbers or names (checking if the substr is in the list, is it an item in the list?).

I think that you have a mistake here:

```
   for el in self.list:
        if substr in self.list:
            res.append(el)
```

Why would you loop through all the items in the list, and then for each one, ignore it (!) and check whether the substr is in self.list?  If you are checking if the substr is in self.list (which I don't think is correct here), then you don't need the loop.  If you are looping, then for each el in self.list you want to do something with el.

Maybe you meant something like:

```
   for el in self.list:
        if substr in el:
            res.append(el)
```

But I don't think that works.

It seems to me that you need separate functions for phone and name.  For phone, you would have:

```
   for el in self.list:
        if substr == el.name:
            res.append(el)
```

Similarly for phone.

Comment: Yes you're right, the code:
`for el in self.list:
        if substr in el:
            res.append(el)`

don't work, I get the next error: in findSubStr if substr in el: TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable

If I use the code:
`for el in self.list:
        if substr in self.list:
            res.append(el)`
They nothing searching! I  did as you said and it works !!! Thank you very much!
Very well, there are such sites were highly skilled programmers share their experience and knowledge!

Comment: Glad to help! It is also encouraging to me, as I am still much newer to Python than to the other languages I'm working in; encouraging to know that I've actually learned something :-)